# Get an error message from a SQL query back into Python

Tags: python, sql, subprocess, sqlcmd

I need to be able to tell if SQL queries kicked off by Python have failed. So far I have:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['sqlcmd', '-E -m-1 -S 1070854A\AISP -i NewStructures.sql >>process.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
print err
```

But it is not liking the SQLCMD parameters. Output says

```
Sqlcmd: '-E -S 1070854A\AISP -i NewStructures.sql': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.
```

These parameters work when typing them into the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to provide the parameters separately, like: '-E', '-m', '-1', '-S' and so on.

Comment: I'm really close. This gives the output of the query, but I need to retrieve only error messages. I feel like one little adjustment will do it...

    import subprocess
    import datetime
    
    command_process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['sqlcmd', '-E', '-V1', '-S', '1070854A\AISP', '-i', 'NewStructures.sql'],
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]
    
    print command_output

Answer (score 0):

`'-E -m-1 -S 1070854A\AISP -i NewStructures.sql >>process.log'` is interpreted as one single argument, that's why you get this error. You need to split the arguments to make this work.

Seen as you're trying to use a redirection in your shell command, you could use something like this:

```
import subprocess
with open('process.log', 'ab') as logfile:
    logfile.seek(0, 2)
    p = subprocess.Popen(['sqlcmd', '-E', '-m-1', '-S', '1070854A\AISP', '-i', 'NewStructures.sql'], stdout=logfile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
```

`out` will be emty anyway, as stdout is redirected to a file.

Redirection using `>` or `>>` only works with `shell=True`.

Comment: Thanks! This works to kick off the query; but I also need to append to the logfile (not overwrite, this will be a nightly process). 

Also how do I retrieve the SQL error message after this is done?

Comment: using the `'ab'` filemode when opening the file you open it for appending, not overwriting. If you get an error, it probably will be in `err` (if sqlcmd writes it to stderr). If you want more flexibility, you could try to connect directly to the db (using [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/) or [pyodbc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc))

Comment: I broke the query and added "print err" to the end of the script, but am getting an empty line. Also the logfile is being overwritten.

Comment: seems on windows a seek to the end of the file opened for append is only performed on the first write, i only tried it on linux and here it worked fine. anyway, manually adding a seek should fix it. empty line for err means there isn't anything printed to it.

Comment: Is it going to the logfile? In that case `sqlcmd` would be printing everything to stdout, in which case you'd have to processs that. or maybe it has some command line switch...?